# Why is access to shared folder via PC name independent from access via IP address?

Tags: windows, shared-folders

Why it is that when I browse to a shared folder in Windows using, say, the PC's name...

`\\pc-name\c\folder`

...and provide credentials, and then browse again but this time use the IP address...

`\\_ipaddress_\c\folder`

... I need to enter the credentials again, even though the first folder still provides access to the files?

Comment: So you can connect to a share with 2 different users at the same time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layer which stores credentials doesn't know about the host's IP address – it is given only the name you've entered and stores credentials under that name only. It doesn't do any address lookups on its own.

---

Only Microsoft knows *exactly* why it works that way. However, there may be several reasons for this:

- The IP address might be dynamic. On a simple workgroup LAN where all names are resolved through NetBIOS or LLMNR, you probably won't even notice that some cheap routers forget previous leases and give you a different IP address every time. As a result, the address which belonged to host A last week might belong to host B now, with different credentials.
- SMB is not limited to just IPv4. The same fileserver could be accessed through IPv4 today and through IPv6 tomorrow (in the latter case the server will have both addresses available). Storing credentials under the hostname makes things easier.

  SMB actually *predates* the widespread usage of IP on LANs (it was created at roughly the same time as IPv4 was). In the Windows NT 4.x days, the same file server might have been accessible through IPv4, through NetWare's IPX, and/or MAC-level "NetBEUI". (AFAIK, in some of those cases, it wasn't even *possible* to access servers by just their address – you had to use the name.)
- The NetBIOS-based SMBv1 supported "virtual hosting", in the sense that the client always sent a packet indicating which host *name* it wanted to access. (This might have been mandatory for some LAN protocols, but in any case remained in IPv4/TCP.)

  This NetBIOS Session Protocol feature could have in theory allowed the same system to act as different servers with different credentials depending on what name you used to reach it, and personally I suspect it might have been actually used by protocol gateways, e.g. to allow IPv4-only clients to access IPX-only servers and vice versa. The gateway would have just a single address on either side, and would change its behavior based on the name, just like HTTP "reverse proxies" do these days.

  (SMBv3 supports something *similar*, and I've read that Azure Cloud actually uses load-balancers which rely on it.)

---

In the end, it's similar to HTTP vhosts and cookies. Just because the browser stores a cookie indicating that you're logged in at `https://superuser.com`, it will not give that out if you visit `https://151.101.1.69`.